# Massless neutrinos and Chirality

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, neutrinos, spinors, chirality

The massless neutrinos can be represented by two component Weyl spinors. Then how does one say that it is an eigenstate of the chirality operator $\gamma^5$, which is a $4\times 4$ matrix and can act on $4\times 1$ column?

Comment: Simply think of a Weyl Spinor as a Dirac spinor where the other two components are set to zero. Equivalently, a Weyl spinor (of chirality +1 belongs to  the two-dimensional subspace with eigenvalue 1 under the action of the projection operator $P_+=\frac{(1-\gamma^5)}2$.

Comment: @suresh Write this as an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply think of a Weyl Spinor as a Dirac spinor where the other two components are set to zero. Equivalently, a Weyl spinor (of chirality +1) belongs to the two-dimensional subspace with eigenvalue 1 under the action of the projection operator $P_+=\frac{(1-\gamma^5)}2$. For negative chirality, use the other projection operator, i.e., $P_-=\frac{(1+\gamma^5)}2$.

This is in response to @neuneck's suggestion though I don't understand the motivation for it. :-)

Comment: It's a full answer to the question, that's why! +1